# How to make webpack support extension alias

Tags: webpack

Currently we can only have webpack support alias for whole module, but I want to have webpack automatically map all file with one extension to another. Ex

```
src
|    style.less
|    main.js
```

in `main.js`, if I do

```
import './style.css'
```

with following configure (supposed to be)

```
resoloveExtensions: {
    css: ['css', 'less']
}
```

webpack will pickup `style.less`, transform it and return

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

resolveExtensions aren't used as 'alternative' extensions, but as extensions when none is provided.

First off, you usually want to keep the defaults of `["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js"]`. In this case, you want to add two more: `["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js", ".css", ".less"]`.

After this, you will be able to require `style.less` from `main.js` like this: `import './style';`. Webpack will then try to find a file with the name `style` and any of the extensions in resolveExtensions!

Comment: I understand this and have been doing so, but what I actually want is more like extension mapping, map from `css` to `[css, less]`. So if I do, `import './style'`, or `import './style.css'`, result would be the same

Comment: If you want to do that you will probably have to write your own loader. Are you sure you really want to do this? It's a very confusing thing, since you'll be doing an import of something that looks like a CSS file, but it'll have to go through a LESS loader etc.

Comment: I kinda want to do it, since I'm using Aurelia, which doesn't have much interest in supporting non-standard syntax, so i can't do `<require from='./style.less'></require>` without modifying their code in `node_modules`

It would be good if i can
`<require from='./style.css'></require>`
and `style.less` will be loaded